# spring boot app with amqp stuck in blocked mode

Tags: spring-amqp

my spring boot app with amqp rabbitMQ hangs without errors in one of the environments. The same config works ok in another.
The thread dump shows,

```
"main" - Thread t@32
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <e62a7fa> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.beforeAccess(ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottleAdapter.beforeAccess(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:243)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:184)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:167)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:815)
- locked <5d300728> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:550)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
- locked <1c4259b2> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
```

and then all the AMQP consumer threads are in BLOCKED state,

```
"AMQPConsumerThread_20" - Thread t@100
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.isActive(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    - waiting to lock <5d300728> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "main" t@32
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1000(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1310)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

The SpringBoot app then waits with the last line on console,

```
2017-02-08T17:48:26.91-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-02-08 17:48:26   [AMQPConsumerThread_1] INFO  o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - 
Created new  connection: SimpleConnection@64f05682 
[delegate=amqp://b489be6b-b6e5-41b5-8f31-3be3acac4518@x.y.z.w:5672/daad99cf-fa24-40fe-b0d1-f9312fb583be, localPort= 57509]
```

**EDIT**

when I drop the consumer count down to 1, the BLOCKED state goes away and the main thread state is as follows,

```
"main" - Thread t@32
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <79908042> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.beforeAccess(ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottleAdapter.beforeAccess(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:243)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:184)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:167)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:815)
- locked <4f3dcc9> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:550)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
- locked <1a60fd96> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
```

But the app still does not start.
the rabbitmq webconsole shows the consumer connected with the last line in logs,

```
2017-02-08T18:36:09.99-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-02-08 18:36:09 [AMQPConsumerThread_1] INFO  o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: SimpleConnection@39271079 
[delegate=amqp://b489be6b-b6e5-41b5-8f31-3be3acac4518@10.146.54.74:5672/daad99cf-fa24-40fe-b0d1-f9312fb583be, localPort= 32880]
```

what am I missing?
thanks

Comment: Would be great to have that Spring Boot application somewhere (on GitHub?) shared to let us play with that locally.

Comment: thanks, but it's kinda difficult to put the whole app up on github. Strange thing is that the exact config works in another environment just fine. we tried to drop the consumers down to just 1, but no dice. Was wondering if there are any pointers to how I can go about troubleshooting this... thanks

Comment: Spring Boot version?

Comment: 1.4.1 there are many older spring boot dependencies from 1.2.8, 1.3.5 but they get upgraded to 1.4.1 because of one of the embedded jars with 1.4.1 version

Comment: OK. Good. But anyway would be great to have some simple app to play from our side. Maybe when you minimize it, you'll figure out what causes a dead lock.

Comment: You need to post the complete thread dump someplace.

Comment: Looks like some throttling in the `SimpleAsyncTaskExcecutor` what are your concurrency settings? Try using a `ThreadPoolTaskExcecutor` in the listener container (with a large enough pool size for your concurrency).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G7Y2nUCi - single consumer

Comment: http://pastebin.com/94N6gtt6 - multi consumers with BLOCKED state

Comment: Are you using a custom `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` with a concurrency limit? The default one has no such limit but the thread dump implies you have a limit set.

Comment: yes I have.


   
    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
         LOGGER.info("<----- Configuring TaskExecutor service with concurrentLimit:{}  ----->", consumerMaxPoolSize);
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("AMQPConsumerThread_");
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(consumerMaxPoolSize);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }```

Comment: ok thanks @GaryRussell let me try to play with concurrency limit and deploy again . thanks much

Comment: @GaryRussell gary thanks much for the analysis. So over a period of time I had increased the queues to 2 and was using async task executor with concurrency limit. And the numbers were, I guess, starving the app or inadequate wrt the # of consumers. As per your suggestion, I removed the limit and am enforcing upper bound via just max consumers for each queue. Was the clue in thread dump - `ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable` ? Also, if you write this as answer I will accept it. Thanks much for the help.

Comment: Yes, the thread dump pointed to the problem. Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This...

```
"main" - Thread t@32
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <79908042> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.beforeAccess(ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottleAdapter.beforeAccess(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:243)
at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:184)
```

Indicates the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is at its thread limit (`setConcurrencyLimit`). This check is only performed if you have set a limit.

This won't proceed until some task terminates. Since the consumer threads are long-lived, that will likely not happen.